# How do I build a trap?

Tags: fallout-4

So I'm trying to build a trap on the bridge leading into sanctuary.

I placed a pressure plate and a tesla trap, then I wired them up to power.  Once I exited the workshop menu I 'activated' the pressure plate by interacting with it and it disappeared.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: In my experience with building things like this, pressure plates "activate" or "go down" too far and they end up inside the floor. If you go into your workshop, do you still see your pressure plate?

Comment: @chaseC no, but the wire leading to where they are supposed to be is still there.  I also went under the bridge but I didn't see the pressure plate there either.

Comment: They don't disappear after they are used do they? I know the Tesla coils have to be repaired sometimes. Interesting issue.

Comment: @ChaseC I don't know, but it doesn't seem like the coil was triggered though.  I think its probably a bug.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't disarm it? I'm pretty sure if you come across mines/traps/whatever in the wild "activate" is the keyword for when you disarm it and put it in your inventory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traps work exactly as you'd expect - basically [in an identical manner to lights and other electrical devices](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/242604/52800). If you've had a pressure plate fall through the floor I'd call this a bug. It's likely it didn't agree with you placing it exactly on the floor and some clipping issue occurred when you stood on it.

The other thing I came across is that you can effortlessly break these traps (especially the tesla trap) just by having it on. To repair a broken trap in Workshop mode, press E with the item selected.

[image: pressure plate trap simple setup]

The things to notice are only the "metal" section of the pressure plate depresses, when it does the red light goes green. When there is no pressure the green light will go red. While the light is green, power will pass to connected devices. While the light is red, it won't.