# How do I connect the terminal to the turret

Tags: fallout-4

So I'm playing Fallout 4, and I've just built a terminal. I've heard it can turn turrets on and off, so I tried connecting one. Problem is, it won't let me attach a wire! Can you *really* turn turrets on and off? If you can, what do I do?

**Update:** I know how to connect a wire. The problem is, it won't allow me to connect a wire from the terminal to the turret. Normally, objects that can be attached using a wire are highlighted in white. The turret is not.

**Update #2:** *I guess it's not possible to connect it, and now, I don't understand why I would want to turn turrets off. Thanks for trying to help, guys, and sorry for the hassle. Stupid me :P*

Comment: This question is basically identical to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242596/how-do-i-connect-power-to-a-light-bulb) on the grounds you're talking about the same mechanic.

Comment: @kalina I updated the question. I wasn't asking how to attach wires, I was wondering why it wouldn't allow me to attach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the terminal and turret within range? I've never personally used a turret with a terminal, but I've had troubles linking power to objects because they aren't close enough.

Comment: You can try putting the turret close to the terminal and connecting it. Then you can move the turret away - it will turn RED when you get too far for the wire.

Answer (score 1):

Be in build mode (and have a wire crafted). Focus the turret and check the options carefully. I can't remember the key for it, but an "attach wire" appears somewhere.

Here is a video on how to do it :).

Comment: I know it's possible to attach a wire and I know how, but it's not letting me connect a terminal to a turret for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Attaching a wire (and thus a terminal) to a turret works if the turret **requires** power!  You cannot, for example, attach a wire to a MachineGun turret, because they have no place/interface/**NEED** for it!

If you want to somehow remote control (turn off, turn on, change targeting parameters) for your MachineGun and Heavy MachineGun you're just out of luck.  It would be cool, but the trade-off in having them be "self-powered" is not having an interface with which to control them via terminal.

Hope this helps!